# How to add a string length constraint in Hasura GraphQL?

Tags: hasura

In the Hasura console, I have a field for a table that is of type string and I wish for this field to be limited to 7 characters. What kind of regex or expression do you add for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added in the Hasura console a constraint under check expression:
`length(colour_code) = 7`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Postgres check constraint on the column to make sure that the limit is enforced by the database, no need for a regex.

```sql
ALTER TABLE your_table
  ADD CONSTRAINT length_check CHECK (char_length(your_column) <= 7);
```

Comment: @pizzae Does this work for your scenario?

Comment: I had a similar approach, but I added this via the Hasura console GUI which was more simpler for me and easier to manage, since your answer is about SQL but I have no idea how to add this or how this can be managed (edited, deleted) so easily